# Initialising security provider at application startup - Necessary?

Tags: android

I've nearly finished my first android app and am just reviewing some of Google's pre-release checklists and one item in particular caught my eye on [this](https://developer.android.com/docs/quality-guidelines/core-app-quality) page. Under the network section, it states: *"If the application uses Google Play services, the security provider is initialized at application startup"*

My app has In App Purchases, so utilises Google billing, which I'm assuming falls under the Google Play services (please correct me if I'm wrong!).

The problem I have with initialising the security provider at app startup is that the Google Billing code is only executed when the user goes to a certain part of the app (likely only a small proportion of users). If the user doesn't (or cannot) update their version of the Google Services, I don't want to prevent them from using the rest of the app (which doesn't utilise any Google play services).

Is it possible to move this provider check to a specific part of my app rather than on application start as suggested? Or have I misunderstood how this works?